# doctrine2 addSelect subquery to return multiple rows

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have a subquery and need to return multiple rows, but I am getting this error:

```
 SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

And Doctrine puts my subquery as scalar:

```
(SELECT m2_.id FROM movie_genres m2_ LEFT JOIN moviesgenres_movies m4_ ON m2_.id = m4_.moviesgenres_id LEFT JOIN movies m3_ ON m3_.id = m4_.movies_id WHERE m3_.id = m0_.id) AS sclr_7
```

I need multiple rows to be returned - is it possible?

Comment: Can you add the code?

Comment: Yes of course it is possible, but we need to see how you perform the query first... because from what you state here, it's wrong.